# remove space from specific column by bash

Tags: bash

I am new of bash command and I really appreciate your help.

I have a file like this

```
ATOM      1  N   LYS P1852      10.932   0.523 -24.701  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2  HN1 LYS P1852      11.571   0.864 -25.419  1.00  0.00
ATOM      3  HN2 LYS P1852      10.431   1.305 -24.278  1.00  0.00
ATOM      4  HN3 LYS P1852      10.154   0.023 -25.132  1.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CA  LYS P1852      11.556  -0.319 -23.640  1.00  0.00
```

and I need to remove space from specific position (position 30 let say) for all the lines. The output has to be as follow:

```
ATOM      1  N   LYS P1852     10.932   0.523 -24.701  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2  HN1 LYS P1852     11.571   0.864 -25.419  1.00  0.00
ATOM      3  HN2 LYS P1852     10.431   1.305 -24.278  1.00  0.00
ATOM      4  HN3 LYS P1852     10.154   0.023 -25.132  1.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CA  LYS P1852     11.556  -0.319 -23.640  1.00  0.00
```

I was trying sed and other commands but no solution until now has worked.

Thanks you

Comment: `sed 's/\(.\{29\}\) \(.*\)/\1\2/' file` will work, but I don't think that it's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut`:

```
cut --complement -c 30 input.txt
```

From the manual:

```
   -c, --characters=LIST
          select only these characters
   --complement
          complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields
```

`--complement` is GNU `cut` specific, if that is not available:

```
cut -c -29,31- input.txt
```

Above commands remove any character at position 30. If you only want to remove space:

```
sed -E 's/^(.{29}) /\1/' input.txt
```

Comment: cut -c -29,31- input.txt and sed -E 's/^(.{29}) /\1/' input.txt both works. Moreover, I really appreciate the explanation con -c and --complement. Thanks again